# Anti integral windup method for analog integrator

Tags: operational-amplifier, analog, feedback

I have found the following topology for an integrator/lowpass filter in a feedback system in an existing circuit .

[image]

I know that the transistors act somehow as a limit of the amplifier, but I am not sure how this works. Can someone explain this?

Furthermore is this the standard method for anti-windup in analog integrators? Are there easier methods with diodes?

Comment: As connected, those ARE diodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know that the transistors act somehow as a limit of the amplifier,
> but I am not sure how this works. Can someone explain this?

I agree, it worked somehow, if it did any. My best guess is that the schematics drawing is incorrect. If that was going to work, wiring has to be like this, ignore the component values:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqp80J.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Q1 conducts when the "OPA output (Vc1)" > V1 
Q2 conducts when the "OPA output < V2

> Furthermore is this the standard method for anti-windup in analog
> integrators? Are there easier methods with diodes?

There is no standard in this area. Oh dear, that would be a terrible PE idea to limit engineering. You can use Zener diodes, too.

---

Two Zener diodes:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLseJT.png)</sup>

A Zener diode and a bridge diode:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fkwRs1.png)</sup>

Comment: Hey Jay, Thank you very much for this explanation. It gets clearer now. But how would you realize it with zener diodes? Or is the advantage here that I can tune the breakthrough voltage exactly to my needs in comparison to zener diodes?

Comment: @phkloth with adjustable limit settings, you have freedom of choosing the "range", how much the integrator can accumulate the error signal, independent to the Integration Coefficient (integral gain). I will add Zener stuff in the post.

Comment: Hey Jay, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @phkloth , Glad to be a little help.